# How can I email an embedded HTML page?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, html

I want to send an email from Outlook that is created using HTML; however when I click send the recipient sees the email as text of the HTML code. How can I have it appear as an HTML page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">


        <title>Message for you</title>

    </head>
```

Comment: This is not programming question. It's off-topic. Anyway, there should be `mail format` or something similar in options. Set it to HTML

Answer (score 2):

You need a plugin to do this. Take a look at http://outlookhtmleditor.codeplex.com/. Another option is to write a program to send html emails using your outlook smtps service.